# How to remove all children of contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript

I need to delete all children of a div after clicking enter.
There is a div and event listener below.

```
<div id = "area" contenteditable="true"></div>

document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
        document.getElementById("area").addEventListener("keypress" , public_mode);
}

function public_mode(){
    var key = window.event.keyCode;
      if (key == 13) {
         sendMessage();
    }
}

function sendMessage(){
    var area = document.getElementById("area");
    while (area.firstChild) {
        area.removeChild(area.firstChild);
    }
}
```

As you can see the contenteditable elements is added an element in according with clicking enter - it depends on browser what element will be added.In my case I use chrome and here are inserted div.
So, the result after clicking enter on the area but **without removing**

```
<div id = "area" contenteditable = "true">
     Sckoriy
     <div></div>
</div>
```

and , with removing

```
<div id = "area" contenteditable = "true">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
</div>
```

But , the needed result is

```
 <div id = "area" contenteditable = "true">
     //Empty
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code mostly works, however there were two main issues.

- `keyCode` is deprecated. you should be using `key` which turns the syntax of searching for a key into looking for a string. This means instead of `13` you just check to see if `key` is `Enter`.
- Secondly you need to pass the event to your `public_mode` function so that you can read the `key` that has been pressed when the event occurs. You also need to use `preventDefault` to prevent it from adding a new line after removing everything from the original contentEditable area when it *does* detect `Enter`

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    document.getElementById("area").addEventListener("keypress", public_mode);
  }

  function public_mode(event) {
    var key = event.key;
    if (key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      sendMessage();
    }
  }

  function sendMessage() {
    var area = document.getElementById("area");
    while (area.firstChild) area.removeChild(area.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```css
#area {
  min-width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="area" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: I should find out what does the preventDefault() do more.I know that when this method is called on account of sending a form the page is not reload.In my case the prevent is purposed to prevent adding a new line having clicked enter.

Comment: @Sckoriy If you think of each element, some elements have default functionality when they're generated. a.e. hitting enter in Textareas creates a new line, hitting a Submit button in a form performs a network request, etc) The question then is - since these event functions are built-in when these elements are added, what if you don't want them to work exactly as described? The workaround is that you can add a new event listener to the same event as the default is watching for, and by calling `event.preventDefault()` within the new event listener you can stop default behavior from triggering.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the key event as an argument to your function.

Also, if you do not want the newline entered in your div, you can prevent the event from continuing with `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    const area = document.getElementById('area')
    area.addEventListener('keypress', public_mode);
    area.focus();
  }
}

function public_mode(event) {
  if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
    sendMessage();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function sendMessage() {
  const area = document.getElementById('area');
  while (area.firstChild) {
    area.removeChild(area.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="area" contenteditable="true">Press Enter to erase me!</div>
```

Comment: @zfrisch, I simply give an alternative way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the innerHTML proprety to an empty string;

```
area.innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: There is no difference between my way of removing and this one.In addition , your way is much slower ;

Answer (score 0):

target the dom by id

```
var s = document.getElementById("area");
```

save the number of childrens

```
var num = s.children.length;
```

and remove the num of childs of element

```
for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
   s.children[0].remove()
 }
```

and inner for some thext

```
s.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: The answer has aldready been given.The decision is to call preventDefault()method.It doesn't depend on with way the elements will be deleted.

Comment: @Sckoriy yep I see, need the preventDefault(), is the right answer